# Get user's current location once with permission

Tags: android, android-location

I'm building an application and I need to get the current location of the user. The process is i want to check first if the SDK version of the user's android version is 23 - Marshmallow, if it is, then it request permission.

If the user will allow, it will enable or turn on the location. if the user will deny, it will request again.

However if the user's android version is lower than 23 then it proceeds to the process:

**the application gets the location and then stores the latitude and longitude into a double variable and can be access to other methods.**

Can you show me how to properly implement this function? like a step by step process. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}}
```

onConnected is the callback you get after you implement GoogleApiClientCallback methods. Above method will only fetch lattitude and longitude of last known location. Refer @jitesh mohite answer for prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

following will be the which would solve your problem

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

// used to check and request runtime permission for marshmellow and start tracking of location

```
 private void requestRunTimePermissionAndStartTracking() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            // Marshmallow+
            if (!checkPermission(getBaseContext())) {
                requestPermission(mActivity, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                     // get location here
            }
        } else {
           // get location here
        }
    }


// check whether we are having location permission for marshmellow
    public static boolean checkPermission(Context context) {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    }

// used to request for location permission.
    public static void requestPermission(Activity activity , int code) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow " +
                    "in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission
                    .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission
                    .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, code);
        }
    }
```

if user accept location request in marshmellow devices override below code

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Util.showToast(getBaseContext(), getBaseContext().getString(R.string
                            .loc_permission_granted));
                    Util.startActivityAndLocationTracking(getApplicationContext());
                } else {
                    Util.showToast(getBaseContext(), getBaseContext().getString(R.string
                            .loc_permission_denied));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir how do i get the user's location? i need to store it, and your comment only shows the permission request. no location is given.

Comment: you can use below link for reference https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html